ytdlp download video with fixed output path
By default, ytdl adds an extension to the file and I am trying to avoid that.
I created the function below to save video files exactly at output_path (will be further used by some other function).
import logging
import yt_dlp as youtube_dl
from typing import Callable, Any, Optional
import os

def download_video(url: str, output_path: str, progress_hook_func: Callable[[dict], Any] = lambda d: None):
    downloaded_file_path: Optional[str] = None

    def _progress_hook(d):
        nonlocal downloaded_file_path
        progress_hook_func(d)
        if d['status'] != 'finished':
            return
        downloaded_file_path = d['filename']

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestvideo[height<=720]+bestaudio/best[height<=720]',
        'outtmpl': output_path,
        'quiet': True,  # Suppress console output
        'progress_hooks': [_progress_hook],
        'logger': logging.Logger("quiet", level=60),
        'postprocessors': []
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])
    if downloaded_file_path is not None and downloaded_file_path != output_path:
        os.rename(downloaded_file_path, output_path)

def test():
    download_video(r"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ot2IGEPbe4I", "test", lambda d: print(d))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()

However, there is an error:
File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\srcs\algo\download_videos.py", line 60, in download_video
    os.rename(downloaded_file_path, output_path)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'test.f251.webm' -> 'test'

'filename' isn't really filename, it's a tempfile-like path. I checked the working directory and its saved as 'test.webp' instead of 'test.f251.webm'
How can I save the video to a fixed path with no extension?

What is the traceback of the error, which should point to the specific line in your code causing the error?

I guess downloaded_file_path is 'test.f251.webm' and os.rename is telling you that there is no file with that name in your current working directory (but maybe in some other directory, which you didn't specify by giving its absolute or relative path).

@mkrieger1 I double checked with both relative and absolute path and it results in the same error

Have you manually checked in the file browser where the 'test.f251.webm' file is located and if it exists at all? If you have double checked but it still results in the same error you have made a mistake when double checking.

@mkrieger1 yes I have double checked and 'test.webm' is created instead of 'test.f251.webm'

Then if test.webm exists, and test.f251.webm doesn't exist, you cannot rename test.f251.webm to test.webm and that's why you get an error.

@mkrieger and my question is not how to solve the error, its how can I get ytdlp to save the file as test instead of test + ext

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

To download a video with ytdlp to a fixed output path in Python, you can use the following steps:
Install ytdlp if not already installed. You can install it using pip install yt-dlp.
Use the following Python code:`
import yt_dlp

def download_video_with_fixed_path(url, output_path):
    ydl_opts = {
        'outtmpl': output_path + '/%(title)s.%(ext)s'
    }
    with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])

# Replace 'your_video_url' with the actual URL of the video
# and 'your_output_path' with the desired output path
video_url = 'your_video_url'
output_path = 'your_output_path'
download_video_with_fixed_path(video_url, output_path)`


Please dont answer using AI generated result
